# iOS App crashes when accessing a contact from Exchange Global Address List

Tags: ios, cordova, exception, cordova-plugins, ios10

I have an application build up on cordova framework and I'm using a plugin called cordova-plugin-contacts (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts) in order to access the number of a contact.

Whenever I choose a contact from my contacts, the number of the contact is picked up properly in both iOS 9 and 10. However this doesn't occur when I access it from groups contacts in Exchange Global Address List. As soon as I try to pick up the contact the application Crashes in iOS10 while in iOS9, it works just fine.

I have tried to debug both iOS 9  and 10 just to see the point that there is an issue as in iOS 10 the exception is on the compiled code. In iOS 9 there is a method which seems to be the first to be called when I choose a contact.

```
   // Called after a person has been selected by the user.
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    CDVContactsPicker* picker = (CDVContactsPicker*)peoplePicker;
    NSNumber* pickedId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];

    if (picker.allowsEditing) {
        ABPersonViewController* personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
        personController.displayedPerson = person;
        personController.personViewDelegate = self;
        personController.allowsEditing = picker.allowsEditing;
        // store id so can get info in peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel
        picker.pickedContactDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pickedId, kW3ContactId, nil];

        [peoplePicker pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
    } else {
        // Retrieve and return pickedContact information
        CDVContact* pickedContact = [[CDVContact alloc] initFromABRecord:(ABRecordRef)person];
        NSArray* fields = [picker.options objectForKey:@"fields"];
        NSDictionary* returnFields = [[CDVContact class] calcReturnFields:fields];
        picker.pickedContactDictionary = [pickedContact toDictionary:returnFields];

        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:picker.pickedContactDictionary];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:picker.callbackId];

        [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

However, in iOS10 it seems that application crashes before the call of that method. The exception I receive is:

```
2016-11-18 11:37:17.301332 myAppName[417:118946] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1859da1c0 0x18441455c 0x1859da108 0x18e159320 0x18e12a0e4 0x1858cdfb8 0x1858c4a64 0x18e12a030 0x18e129f1c 0x18e168f50 0x18fc16ce8 0x18fc43e6c 0x18f06b900 0x18f110f28 0x18f1116f4 0x1033c925c 0x1033c921c 0x1033ce284 0x185987f2c 0x185985b18 0x1858b4048 0x18733a198 0x18b8a02fc 0x18b89b034 0x1000e5e14 0x1848985b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In the debug console I typed bt and I received:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1d0a2, 0x00000001849aa014 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001849aa014 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000184a72450 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x000000018491e3e0 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x00000001843e92d4 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 132
    frame #4: 0x0000000184406cc0 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #5: 0x0000000184414844 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
    frame #6: 0x000000018440366c libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #7: 0x0000000184402f84 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 136
    frame #8: 0x0000000184414690 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 364
    frame #9: 0x00000001859da108 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    frame #10: 0x000000018e159320 Contacts`-[CNContact sectionForSortingByFamilyName] + 164
    frame #11: 0x000000018e12a0e4 Contacts`__55-[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) overwritePerson:error:]_block_invoke + 48
    frame #12: 0x00000001858cdfb8 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 100
    frame #13: 0x00000001858c4a64 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 188
    frame #14: 0x000000018e12a030 Contacts`-[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) overwritePerson:error:] + 204
    frame #15: 0x000000018e129f1c Contacts`-[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) detachedPersonWithError:] + 56
    frame #16: 0x000000018e168f50 Contacts`-[CNContactStore(iOSABCompatibility) personFromContact:] + 344
    frame #17: 0x000000018fc16ce8 AddressBookUI`-[CNContact(ABCompatibility) recordFromAddressBook:] + 80
    frame #18: 0x000000018fc43e6c AddressBookUI`-[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController contactPicker:didSelectContact:] + 152
    frame #19: 0x000000018f06b900 ContactsUI`-[CNContactPickerViewController pickerDidSelectContact:property:] + 296
    frame #20: 0x000000018f110f28 ContactsUI`-[CNContactPickerHostViewController pickerDidSelectContact:property:] + 100
    frame #21: 0x000000018f1116f4 ContactsUI`__71-[CNContactPickerExtensionHostContext pickerDidSelectContact:property:]_block_invoke + 60
    frame #22: 0x00000001033c925c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #23: 0x00000001033c921c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #24: 0x00000001033ce284 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1200
    frame #25: 0x0000000185987f2c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #26: 0x0000000185985b18 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1660
    frame #27: 0x00000001858b4048 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    frame #28: 0x000000018733a198 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #29: 0x000000018b8a02fc UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 684
    frame #30: 0x000000018b89b034 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
  * frame #31: 0x00000001000e5e14 myAppName`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd1f938) + 84 at main.m:34
    frame #32: 0x00000001848985b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I attach also a picture that might help. The contacts work fine, but it crashes after choosing contact from exchange server.
[image: Image of the crash. In contacts everything works fine. Only in the exchange server.]

Any help on that, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure NSContactsUsageDescription is in info.plist of your app.

Also the reason for the crash can be because iOS10 uses different class for person picker, so you need to have a check like below :

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"CNContactPickerViewController")) {
    // iOS 9, 10, use CNContactPickerViewController
    CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
    [pr presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    // iOS 8 Below, use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [pr presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar...You mention that the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController works in iOS 8 and bellow. What I found weird is that when you choose a normal contact and not from Exchange Address Global List, it works quite fine. Is there anything in the Exception or In debug console that could help finding the issue?